# How to solve tensor flow cpu dll not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have install `tensorflow v2.1.0` with `python version 3.6.6` and `pip version 20.0.2`. When i try to import tensorflow i got below error.

```
C:\Users\Dexter>python
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dexter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Dexter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Dexter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Dexter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Dexter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

When i searched on google i always get tensorflow-gpu solution i don't have any graphic card in my system. below is info of my display driver. Please help me with this i stuck in this. 
[image]

I  have c++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017

[image]

Comment: How did you install `tensorflow`? `pip`?

Comment: using pip `pip install tensorflow`

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019? I mean ALL of them.

Comment: I have update my question i don't have all C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio but have 2017 and 2013 do we need all 2015,2017 and 2019 to run tensorflow

Comment: Yes, you need all of them, but they're installed via single binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [installation instructions for Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip), Tensorflow 2.1.0 requires *Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, and 2019* - which is what you are (partially) missing. Moreover, *starting with the TensorFlow 2.1.0 version, the msvcp140_1.dll file is required from this package (which may not be provided from older redistributable packages).*

That's why you're getting the error. Install the missing packages following [these instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip). In essence, grab the 2015, 2017 and 2019 Redistributable, all in single package, available from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

Answer (score -1):

Try to install Anaconda make a virtual env. and it will install automatically all the depedencies of the libraries that you want!

Comment: You can find more information at https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/