# I have a problem with tensor flow in pip installed in but cant be able to run

Tags: python, tensorflow

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho12v.png)

I have a problem with the TensorFlow library I pip installed it and while running in python ide it is throwing error. I have attached the image in which you can find the type of error.

Comment: Can you confirm you have installed Tensorflow exactly according to the instructions? See notes e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543207/how-to-solve-tensor-flow-cpu-dll-not-found-error/60543876#60543876

Comment: I  have just installed it by opening command prompt pip install TensorFlow that's it. Then cmd downloaded around 400mb of files.

Comment: Which is why in all likelihood it doesn't work. Follow the manual and let us know if it worked (consider then upvoting the linked answer).

Comment: can you suggest me the site to download the visual c++?

Comment: Have you followed the linked solution?

Comment: yep I have followed as per the instructions first pip installed TensorFlow then GPU then virtualenv and further the visual c++

Comment: Can you confirm that you have installed ALL redistributables? This error points to missing DLLs that are part of these  packages.

Comment: yes I have installed as per the procedure but while running in ide it is showing error