# I installed tensorflow 2.0 but jupyter doesn't see it?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I seem to have a problem with installing tensorflow 2.0. After many attempts finally command "conda list" shows tensorflow 2.0 package successfully installed but when I try to import it in jupyter I get the error:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\giuse\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, 
in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\giuse\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", 
line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\giuse\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", 
line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\giuse\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\giuse\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: There's problem with your NVIDIA driver and CUDA setup. Make sure you have done all that's specified here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Comment: OMG! this sound like rocket science :,(

Comment: I suggest you complete remove tensorflow-gpu, any previously installed NVIDIA driver + CUDA and follow the steps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve tensor flow cpu dll not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543207/how-to-solve-tensor-flow-cpu-dll-not-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

If you have still below error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Try to install the proper version of:

[visual c++ redistributable for visual studio 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Or try virtual environment:

## Creation of the environment

```
conda create -n test_env python=3.x anaconda
```

## Activation

```
conda activate test_env
```

## Deactivation

```
conda deactivate
```

## Getting rid of it

```
conda remove -n test_env --all
```